# Where should I open connection to MongoDB from WCF service

Tags: c#, mongodb, wcf

I am writing a WCF application that will use MongoDB at backend. I am confused where to put these lines.

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("Test");
```

Should I include these lines in every method or some common place?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should avoid reusing connections and let the framework do it for you - basically, let the framework handle connection pooling and don't try to get in its way.  I'm not 100% sure about this for Mongo, but it's certainly true in other areas that use this pattern for ADO.NET, and since the `MongoClient` supports pooling I would assume the same is true here.

Assuming the Mongo implementation works as it should, it will automatically reuse and recycle connections for you - you shouldn't have to worry about that in your code.  Instead, you should be thinking about how to set up your [settings](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.1/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClientSettings.htm) around connection pooling, and thinking about how your WCF service is designed (singleton? single-per-session?  single-per-call?).

So the answer is: that code snippet should appear everywhere you'd need to connect, although the connectionString should probably be stored in one place (such as in `app.config` or `web.config`).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the architecture of your service application.

An important aspect of this is how will you deal when the connection fails and/or is abruptly aborted?  How will you handle reconnects?

As asked above, what's the InstanceContextMode and ConcurrencyMode of your service?  Also: is MongoClient thread safe?

Most of the times, I'd expect to see these types initializations being called in the constructor or somewhere where it gets initialized in a lazy manner.